# How to select unique value from many to many mysql relationship

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi I got confused in this sql case. I am using `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.31-MariaDB`. And let's say I have 3 table `products`, `categories`, and `product_categories` as pivot table.

Here is the data example:

```
products:

|    id    |   name    |
------------------------
| 1        | asd wef   |
| 2        | gggg2222  |
| 3        | pppga 99  |
| 4        | lalala 55 |
```

And for categories:

```
| id | level | parent_id | name     |
-----------------------------------
| 20 | 1     |           | Fashion  |
| 22 | 2     | 20        | Top      |
| 23 | 3     | 22        | T-Shirt  |
| 24 | 3     | 22        | Jacket   |
```

And for the pivot table, product_categories:

```
|  product_id  |  category_id  |
--------------------------------
| 1            | 20            |
| 1            | 22            |
| 1            | 23            |
| 2            | 22            |
| 2            | 20            |
| 3            | 20            |
| 4            | 20            |
```

So as you can see from pivot table only `product_id = 3 & 4` that stop in category level 1. And `product_id = 2` only stop in category level 2.

What I would like to achieve here is when I select from `categories` table. I can count how many product that stopping here. This is example of the data that I want to get.

```
"categories": [
    {
        "id": 20,
        "total_product": 4
        "stopped_product": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 22,
        "total_product": 3
        "stopped_product": 1
    }
]
```

So far I tried using `group by`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM product_categories WHERE product_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4) GROUP BY product_id HAVING category_id=20
```

output:

```
|  product_id  |  category_id  |
--------------------------------
| 1            | 20            |
| 3            | 20            |
| 4            | 20            |
```

Expected Output

```
|  product_id  |  category_id  |
--------------------------------
| 3            | 20            |
| 4            | 20            |
```

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: Ah ya sorry, forgot mentioning about that. I'm using mysql  `Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.31-MariaDB`

Comment: I didn't get what is stopped_product but you can find category-wise product count by query I have posted. And if you mean stopped_product = level than you can add in one more field in select (c.level) and can find that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE to generate a list of stop categories for each product and then `JOIN` that to the `categories` and `product_categories` tables to count the total number of products and number of stopped products for each category:

```
WITH prods AS (
  SELECT product_id, MAX(category_id) AS stop_cat
  FROM product_categories
  GROUP BY product_id
)
SELECT c.id AS category_id, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT pc.product_id) AS total_product,
       SUM(c.id = p.stop_cat) AS stopped_product
FROM categories c
JOIN product_categories pc ON pc.category_id = c.id
JOIN prods p ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
GROUP BY c.id
```

Output (for your sample data)

```
category_id     total_product   stopped_product
20              4               2
22              2               1
23              1               1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=99598d5fa9832c2e0c2bb675550dd6ca)

Comment: I tried this and it does give me what I am looking for. Thank you for your help man :D

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want max values only

```
    SELECT product_id,MAX(category_id) as category_id FROM product_categories WHERE product_id IN (1, 2, 
    3, 4) 
    GROUP BY product_id 
    HAVING category_id=20
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is you can find category-wise product count and ids:

```
SELECT c.name as categoryName, c.level, COUNT(pc.product_id) as productCount, GROUP_CONCAT(pc.product_id) as productIds 
FROM product_categories pc JOIN categories c ON c.id = pc.category_id 
WHERE 1 
GROUP by c.id
```